# PHP (local wamp) - how to print without print dialogue

Tags: php, printing, exec, wamp

Trying to find a good way to print without the print dialogue on my LOCAL wamp installation, in other words the printer is connected to the server.

The best (theoretical) way I have found so far seems to be using PHP's exec function, by either running a .bat that will use notepad to open and print the file or by running notepad and printing form there.

EG:

```
<?php
$exe_tmp = exec('E:\WebServer\www\testprint.bat');

//or

$exe_tmp = exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "E:\WebServer\www\MOSys\ePos\testprint.bat"');
?>
```

testprint.bat

```
NOTEPAD /P E:\WebServer\www\current_reciept.txt
```

Running either of these form cmd.exe works perfectly but when trying to run it using PHP's exec, when $exe_tmp is echoed, I get seemingly nothing and an output of:

```
E:\WebServer\www>NOTEPAD /P E:\WebServer\www\current_reciept.txt
```

If anyone knows why the above don't work when called from exec(); that would be very good, or if anyone knows of another way to bypass the print dialogue that would be excellent.

Cheers
Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer lies here:h[ttp://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28WS.10%29.aspx)

It would result in something like this:

```
$exe_tmp = exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "print /d:\\SERVER\printer e:\WebServer\www\current_reciept.txt"');
```

I din't test it but according to the microsoft site it sends it directly to the queue